# How can I get time slot is in another time slot or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, datetime

I am working on a project in which I need to find out that selected time slot is between another time slot or not. For eg there is a Time slot like 1:00 AM to 2:00 AM  Now I want to get that this time slot is between 12:45 AM to 3:45 AM slot or not?

Comment: Check if startA <= start B && endB <= endA?

Comment: Please be aware that this isn't a code writing service - please show what research you've undertaken, you've already tried, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *generatedStartDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"01:00 AM"];
NSDate *generatedEndDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"03:44 AM"];
NSDate *slotStartDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"01:00 AM"];
NSDate *slotEndDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"03:45 AM"];
NSComparisonResult result = [slotStartDate compare:generatedStartDate];
NSComparisonResult result1 = [generatedEndDate compare:slotEndDate];
if (result != NSOrderedDescending && result1 != NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"IN Between");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NOT IN Between");
}
```

Comment: Note that it maybe be interesting to check that startA <= endA and startB <= endB; else you need to add "one day" (I guess) to endA / endB.

Comment: Note that `NSComparisonResult` is a 3-valued type; `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame`, `NSOrderedDescending`; so `(result == NSOrderedAscending || result == NSOrderedSame)` can be replaced by `(result != NSOrderedDescending)` (and similarly for `result1`)